# Moving divs, left and right, outside the box

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to move a `div` with absolute position from left to right or right to left, outside the window with JQuery?

CSS:

```
s1 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -1202px;
}
s2 {
   position: absolute;
   right: -1202px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $("#s1").animate({
       left:"1202px"
   },1500);
$("#s2").animate({
       right:"1202px"
   },1500);
});
```

Comment: Yes...but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Why 1202px?

Comment: It was just an example. It's not possible. You can move the div either left or right ! I don't know how it works

Comment: What doesn't work with this code? (apart from the css not having `#`)

Comment: It only moves to the left, it goes outside the window and you can not see it. This is what I want, to be hidden. But when it moves to the right, it will not be hidden, you can see it with scrolling right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but note that your CSS contains an error :

```
s1 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -1202px;
}
s2 {
   position: absolute;
   right: -1202px;
}
```

Should be :

```
#s1 {
   position: absolute;
   left: -1202px;
}
#s2 {
   position: absolute;
   right: -1202px;
}
```

It probably comes from here : **if you don't set a position (absolute, relative or fixed) to an element, you can't use top/left/right/bottom property**.

*Static position (default value) doesn't care about that.*

Scrollbar handling : if you don't want your user to be able to scroll to the elements you move outside the window :

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You can put it on `body` or any wrapping element. It will keep vertical scrolling if needed, but will remove horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I forgot to put # here, so no css error. It only moves to the left, it goes outside the window and you can not see it. This is what I want, to be hidden. But when it moves to the right, it will not be hidden, you can see it with scrolling right !

Comment: Oh ok, it's just about the scrollbar ?